# How does docker run differ from running a command from a shell within the container

Tags: shell, docker, permissions, logstash

I'm having a problem where I get permission denied when attempting to run logstash within the container and accessing configurations provided via a host volume. But if I explicitly run the command within a shell it works fine.

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD/logstash/config":/etc/logstash/conf.d:Z logstash:latest logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d
The error reported is:
  Permission denied - /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf

$ docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD/logstash/config":/etc/logstash/conf.d:Z logstash:latest sh -c 'logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d'
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 4
Logstash startup completed

$ docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD/logstash/config":/etc/logstash/conf.d:Z logstash:latest ls -lZ /etc/logstash/conf.d
total 4
-rw-------. 1 1000 1000 system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0:c78,c159 125 Mar  9 17:57 logstash.conf
```

This tells me that there's something different about the environment in the shell but I have no clue what would cause these permissions issues.

Comment: And would a `sh -c 'logstash:latest ls -lZ /etc/logstash/conf.d'` work better?

Comment: I've clarified the question. But yes, that's basically what I've had to do to get this to work, but I really would like to understand why.

Comment: What did you do to protect `$PWD/logstash/config` with the right user `logstash`?

Comment: From what I can tell here's what's happening:
1) adding `:Z` modifier to the `-v` parameter sets the correct SELinux labels on the files and directories
2) `logstash` is running as root
These two things allow the `logstash` process to access the host volume.

Comment: OK. I have added your findings in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first clue, I see in the [logstash `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/logstash/blob/4f3a81ff0f152003653eecd60d0c4e1f05ce99f0/2.2/Dockerfile#L43) that its `ENTRYPOINT` is [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/logstash/blob/4f3a81ff0f152003653eecd60d0c4e1f05ce99f0/2.2/docker-entrypoint.sh)

```
# Run as user "logstash" if the command is "logstash"
if [ "$1" = 'logstash' ]; then
    set -- gosu logstash "$@"
fi
```

That would explain the difference between `logstash` and `sh -c 'logstash...'`: the first parameter is no longer `logstash`.

So you need to make sure `$PWD/logstash/config` is, once mounted, accessible to user '`logstash`'.

---

The [OP Mark Caudill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5269771/mark-caudill) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917829/how-does-docker-run-differ-from-running-a-command-from-a-shell-within-the-contai?noredirect=1#comment59543841_35917829):

> 1. adding `:Z` modifier to the `-v` parameter sets the correct SELinux labels on the files and directories
> 2. logstash is running as `root`
> 3. `chcon -R system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0 ./` on each directory being mounted as a host volume
>
> These points allow the `logstash` process to access the host volume.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your questions but this should help ...

`RUN` runs the specified command inside a container at `DOCKER BUILD` time. `ENTRYPOINT` runs the specified command inside a container at `DOCKER RUN` time.

When mounting a volume, the files inside the container that exist inside the image (at build time) will be overwritten. The files inside the container that were created at docker run time will be accessible in the mounted volume, and thus will be accessible both inside the container and from the host.

You should either:

1. Consider using `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `RUN`
2. Use `volumes-from` if you only need to share files between containers